# Adding duplicate rows to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, duplicates, pandas-groupby

I did not figure out how to solve the following question!
consider the following data set:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([['a',1, 2, 3], ['a',4, 5, 6],
                                 ['b',7, 8, 9], ['b',10, 11 , 12]]),
 columns=['id','A', 'B', 'C'])

  id   A    B    C
  a    1    2    3
  a    4    5    6
  b    7    8    9
  b    10   11   12
```

I need to group the data by id and in each group duplicate the first row and add it to the dataset like the following data set:

```
  id   A    B    C    A  B  C
  a    1    2    3    1  2  3
  a    4    5    6    1  2  3
  b    7    8    9    7  8  9
  b    10   11   12   7  8  9
```

I really appreciate it for your help.

I did the following steps, however I could not expand it :

```
df1 = df.loc [0:0 , 'A' :'C']
df3 = pd.concat([df,df1],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `first`, and then concatenate `df` with this result:

```
v = df.groupby('id').transform('first')
pd.concat([df, v], 1)

  id   A   B   C  A  B  C
0  a   1   2   3  1  2  3
1  a   4   5   6  1  2  3
2  b   7   8   9  7  8  9
3  b  10  11  12  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 3):

`cumcount` + `where`+`ffill`

```
v=df.groupby('id').cumcount()==0

pd.concat([df,df.iloc[:,1:].where(v).ffill()],1)
Out[57]: 
  id   A   B   C  A  B  C
0  a   1   2   3  1  2  3
1  a   4   5   6  1  2  3
2  b   7   8   9  7  8  9
3  b  10  11  12  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 2):

One can also try `drop_duplicates` and `merge`.

```
df_unique = df.drop_duplicates("id")
df.merge(df_unique, on="id", how="left")

    id  A_x     B_x     C_x     A_y     B_y     C_y
0   a   1       2       3       1       2       3
1   a   4       5       6       1       2       3
2   b   7       8       9       7       8       9
3   b   10      11      12      7       8       9
```

Comment: this one should be fast :-)

Comment: thanks for all response. I was wondering if I need to duplicate the second row, can I use this solution again? why  drop_duplicate remove the second column?  is there any way to remove the selected rows by drop_duplicate! @Tai

Comment: @AlterNative here I passed in `id` to specify that I want to detect duplicates by this label. By default only the first row will be kept by `drop_duplicates`

Comment: @Tai Thanks again for adding detail.

Comment: @AlterNative There are only a few choices that you can choose from. See [Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for the `keep` parameter.

Comment: @AlterNative what potential selections you want to do? If too complicated, I think you can just create a new df yourself with suitable mapping between `id` and `A`, `B`, `C` and just perform `merge` later with that df.

Comment: @Tai I have a large dataset, for some rows I want to duplicate the first rows and for some of them duplicate the second row, and so on.  I am new to pandas, I think I need to study  mapping and merge subjects to understand them better.

Comment: @AlterNative That's true. Take a look at the documentation for `merge`. The mapping I talked about is a dataframe like `df_unique` in my answer. (Sorry to confuse you if I did.) If you need help I think you can ask another problem if it involves more subtleties. Give an example that fits your real-world problem though. Best.